Feature subset selection using neural network
This listing selects the best features from the 1011 available columns in a given dataset.
The first three columns are dropped because they are useless data.
The dataset is huge. So, they were read in 25 chunks.
Please focus on threshold, feature_importance, and selected_features .
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from collections import Counter

# Path to the dataset
file_path = 'dataset.csv'
output_file_path = 'feature_selection_output.txt'

# Chunk size calculation
total_rows = 1000000
num_chunks = 25
chunk_size = total_rows // num_chunks

# Check for GPU availability
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
if len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')) > 0:
    print("Using GPU")
else:
    print("No GPU found, using CPU")

# Function to process a chunk
def process_chunk(chunk):
    # Fill empty values with zeros
    chunk.fillna(0, inplace=True)

    # Remove the first three columns
    chunk = chunk.iloc[:, 3:]

    # Filter rows based on the first column's value
    chunk = chunk[chunk.iloc[:, 0].astype(str).str.contains('A|B|C')]

    # Separate target and features
    y = chunk.iloc[:, 0]
    X = chunk.iloc[:, 1:]

    # One-hot encode the target column
    y = pd.get_dummies(y)

    return X, y

# Placeholder for selected features count
feature_counter = Counter()

for i, chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv(file_path, chunksize=chunk_size)):
    print(f"Processing chunk {i+1}/{num_chunks}")
    X, y = process_chunk(chunk)

    # Normalize features
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

    # Build and train a simple neural network model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=64, verbose=0)

    # Extract feature importance from the model weights
    weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
    feature_importance = np.mean(np.abs(weights), axis=1)

    # Select features based on importance
    threshold = np.median(feature_importance)
    selected_features = np.where(feature_importance > threshold)[0]

    # Update feature counter
    feature_counter.update(selected_features)

    # Clear the Keras session to free memory
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

# Get the most frequently selected features and sort by frequency in descending order
sorted_features = feature_counter.most_common()

# Save the selected features and their frequencies to a file
with open(output_file_path, 'w') as f:
    for feature, count in sorted_features:
        f.write(f"{feature}: {count}\n")

print(f"Selected features saved to {output_file_path}")


new concept? new name!
    y = chunk.iloc[:, 0]
    ...
    # One-hot encode the target column
    y = pd.get_dummies(y)

Imagine a telephone conversation with a colleague about this code.
Maybe it's a facetime conversation with
Abe Lincoln Bob Newhart.

Yeah, you want to do that with y?
You mean the old y?
Or maybe the new y.
You know, like y-prime.
No, not like that transformer.
You know, the new y, the hot one.
Uhhhh, the one hot one.
Oh, you know what I mean!
No?
Well, let me give it a name so you'll know what I mean.

You had an opening where you could give each concept a distinct name.
Next time, perhaps you will seize the opportunity.
giant number
total_rows = 1000000

I ran out of fingers on one hand to count the powers of ten there.
Prefer to spell it
total_rows = 1_000_000

so we can see at once that you mean "a million".

Please focus on threshold, feature_importance, and selected_features


Series.isin is much faster than Series.str.contains since you're only checking for literal strings (rather than substrings):
- chunk = chunk[chunk.iloc[:, 0].astype(str).str.contains('A|B|C')]
+ chunk = chunk[chunk.iloc[:, 0].isin(list('ABC'))]


inplace will be deprecated in PDEP-8 and is not recommended:
- chunk.fillna(0, inplace=True)
+ chunk = chunk.fillna(0)




That was less important part of the code. Please focus on threshold, feature_importance, and selected_features ..
